# Is it possible to make backgound repeat from bottom left corner of screen to top right?

Tags: css, background, rotation

I have some image pattern, and I want it to strike an element(e.g. body). I could create pseudo element with background and rotate it for n degree, but it's a bad solution because I don't know proportions of the block.

Any ideas how I could achieve it using CSS only?

Comment: With CSS only it's not possible AFAIK

Comment: How about: `background: url(image.jpg) bottom left;`

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a CSS property that does what you want, it can be hacked in.

It's a bit ugly and it's not a real repeat, but it might work for you.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image:
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png"),
        url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ux6.png");
    background-position:
        0% 100%,
        10% 90%,
        20% 80%,
        30% 70%,
        40% 60%,
        50% 50%,
        60% 40%,
        70% 30%,
        80% 20%,
        90% 10%,
        100% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4FD3/

Here I repeated the same image 10 times. You can do it as many times as you want, just add more lines and smaller intervals between the positions (e.g.: 0% 100%, 2% 98%, 4% 96%).

Comment: it solves only half of they problem. I still need rotation alignment.

Answer (score 0):

[image: pattern]

why not making a pattern that will look like it goes slant like the example above

Comment: Because our designer decided that it's a good idea to draw tire trial from corner to corner...